# Setting a new variable to a javascript class instance doesn't change original instance

Tags: javascript

I'm running into a weird problem. When I set a new variable equal to a class instance, the new variable doesn't mutate the class instance.

Currently, I have a class within my class called #cells that is an array containing cells. Each cell has a property called a tile. When I set a new variable, called tempCell = this.#cells[0] and set tempCell.tile = null, this.#cells[0].tile is not 0. Now when I do this.#cells[i].tile = null, and console log this, I get null. Why is this happening? I've attached code to make clear what I'm doing.

```
class Grid {
  #cells
  constructor(gameBoardElement) {
    this.#cells = createBoard(gameBoardElement);
  }
  getEmptyCells() {
    return this.#cells.filter((cell) => cell.tile === null)
  }

  getRandomEmptyCell() {
    let emptyCells = this.getEmptyCells();
    if(emptyCells.length > 0) {
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * emptyCells.length);
      return emptyCells[randomIndex];
    }
  }
  handleRight() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
       if(i % 4 === 3 ) {
        continue;
       }
       this.#combineTwoSquares(i, i+1);
    }
  }

  #combineTwoSquares(firstIndex, secondIndex) {
    let firstCell = this.#cells[firstIndex];
    let secondCell = this.#cells[secondIndex];
    if(firstCell.tile === null) {
      return;
    }
    if(secondCell.tile === null) {



    }
  }
  delete_tiles() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      let cell = this.#cells[i];
      if(cell.tile !== null) {
        cell.tile.remove();
        //This is where the problem arises
cell.tile = null;
//this does not print out null. 
        console.log(this.#cells[i].tile)
      }
    }
  }
  get tiles() {
    let tiles = [];
    this.#cells.forEach((cell) => (tiles.push(cell.tile)));
    return tiles;
  }

}

class Cell {
  #cellElement
  #x
  #y
  #tile
  constructor(cellElement,x,y, tile = null) {
    this.#cellElement = cellElement;
    this.#x = x;
    this.#y = y;
    this.#tile = null;
  }

  set tile(tile) {
    if(tile === null) {
      return;
    }
    this.#tile = tile;
    this.#tile.x = this.#x;
    this.#tile.y = this.#y;
  }

  get tile() {
    return this.#tile;
  }

}

function createBoard(gameBoardElement) {
  let cells = []
  for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    let x = i % 4;
    let y = Math.floor(i/4);
    let cellElement = document.createElement("div");
    cellElement.classList.add("game-cell");
    gameBoardElement.append(cellElement)
    let cell = new Cell(cellElement,x,y);
    cells.push(cell);
  }
  return cells;
}

class Tile {
  #x
  #y
  #value
  #tileElement
  constructor(gameBoard, value = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 2 : 4) {
    this.#tileElement = document.createElement("div");
    this.#tileElement.classList.add("tile");
    gameBoard.appendChild(this.#tileElement);
    this.#tileElement.textContent = value;
    this.#value = value;

  }

  get value() {
    return this.#value;
  }
  set value(value) {
    this.#tileElement.textContent = value
    this.#value = value;
  }

  get x() {
    return this.#x;
  }
  set x(x) {
    this.#x = x;
    this.#tileElement.style.setProperty("--x",this.#x);
  }

  get y() {
    return this.#y;
  }
  set y(y) {
    this.#y = y;
    this.#tileElement.style.setProperty("--y",this.#y);
  }

  remove() {
    this.#tileElement.remove();
  }
}

let gameBoard = document.getElementById("game-board");
window.addEventListener("keydown",handleKeys);
let grid = new Grid(gameBoard);
grid.getRandomEmptyCell().tile = new Tile(gameBoard);


function handleKeys(e) {
    switch(e.key) {
        case "ArrowRight":
            // grid.handleRight();
            grid.delete_tiles();
            // grid.getRandomEmptyCell().tile = new Tile(gameBoard);
            console.log(grid.tiles);
            break;
        default:
        console.log("Not an accurate key");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that can be directly run to immediately see the issue without making anyone guess about the rest of the code.

Comment: Put my full code in the question. It's not too long to read, but the problem occurs in the grid class. I've commented where it happens.

Comment: You have `if(tile === null) { return; }` in the setter of `cell.tile`, it will never be set to `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly returning without doing anything in the setter for the `tile` property in `Cell` when the new value is `null`. You should at least set `this.#tile` to the new value.

```js
set tile(tile) {
    this.#tile = tile;
    if (tile) {
        this.#tile.x = this.#x;
        this.#tile.y = this.#y;
    }
}
```